# jQuery Datepicker - how to get / read default settings

Tags: jquery, default, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use jQuery datepicker only for parsing and formatting dates, but on my actual page I don't want to implement any datepicker.

Now, I set datepicker defaults, e.g.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["de-DE"]);
```

Now my question is, how to READ this default date format, without having any datepicker object?
Thinking of something like ...

```
$.datepicker.getDefaults('dateFormat');
```

...returning me the string "dd.MM.yyyy" - possible?

Comment: By reading the default date format, do you mean the one set by jQueryUI?

Comment: Yes, what I set here:  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["de-DE"]);

Answer (score 3):

The current defaults are stored in `$.datepicker._defaults`, at least in JQuery UI 1.11. Of course, since this is an undocumented internal variable it is subject to change.

Alternatively, store a separate variable `region` which holds the region value. When you call `setDefaults`, also store the `region`:

```
var region="de-DE";
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[region]);
```

Then you can query the values with `$.datepicker.regional[region].dateFormat` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that's a good answer, but it's the way I've found to solve the problem.
I'm copying the current (default) regional settings to another index - ["local"], and using it everywhere I need.

If someone has a better way of doing that, please feel free to post an answer.

**On page load:**

```
$(function () {
    // Default locale = en-GB
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["en-GB"]);

    // Copying to a new index = local
    $.datepicker.regional["local"] = $.datepicker.regional["en-GB"];
});
```

**When I need to refer to any setting:**

```
var month = $.datepicker.regional["local"].monthNames[myMonth];
```

**or**

```
var month = $.datepicker.regional.local.monthNames[myMonth];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get it like this`

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay  : function( date ) {
            var monthsArr = $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNamesShort');
            console.log( monthsArr );
        }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.